# sincronizar duas telas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js

Estou começando a desenvolver um sistema de agenda em rails e estou com o seguinte problema:

1. Digamos que eu tenha duas telas aberta na agenda:

   1.1 - Primeira tela esta aberta no computador do médico.

   1.2 - Segunda tela esta aberta no computador da secretaria.
2. Quando a secretaria modifica algo na tela de agenda, por exemplo, muda o status de paciente de "confirmado" para "sala de Espera".
3. Automaticamente a tela do medico deve ser atualizada.

   3.1 Deve ser atualizada sem o medico dar "f5" na pagina.

   3.2 Essa atualização devera ser automática.

   3.3 E devera atualizar na tela de agendamento do médico somente o status paciente e não toda a tela.

Minha duvida seria, quais serão as ferramentas que precisarei para fazer isso?Será que com angulaJs e nodeJs e rails eu consigo fazer isso?

Comment: O que você precisa é de um mecanismo de comunicação de duas vias. Procure por 'WebSockets' ou 'Pooling'.

Comment: Voto no WebSockets @OnoSendai :). Link com um módulo para angular para utilizar WebSockets (https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket) Só não entendi porque utilizar 2 tecnologias de backend

Comment: @Caputo pode ser uma ou a outra, não há necessidade das duas. Por 'comunicação de duas vias', eu apenas quis dizer que tanto o browser quanto o servidor são ativos (nenhum aguarda exclusiva e passivamente uma mensagem do outro.)

Comment: @OnoSendai, concordei coma sua sugestão ;) só votei pelo WebSockets como sugestão. A segunda parte, onde questionei que não entendi duas tecnologias de back end, é porque o AP colocou NodeJs e RubyOnRails daí questionei sobre as duas tecnologias de backend

Comment: Oh! Desculpe @Caputo, falta de café aqui. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai Disponha ;)

Comment: @OnoSendai: é "polling" e não "pooling"...

Comment: @JoséX. Eu acho que é 'pooling' mesmo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooling_(resource_management)

Comment: @OnoSendai AJAX, WebSockets, long polling, server sent events, comet, tudo isso é relacionado...olhe só alguns links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/in-what-situations-would-ajax-long-short-polling-be-preferred-over-html5-websock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715179/differences-between-websockets-and-long-polling-for-turn-based-game-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling/

Answer (score -1):

Websockets resolvem seu problema.

É um pouco antigo, mas esse Railscasts explica como implementar:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye?view=asciicast

Comment: Veja [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/137387).

Answer (score -4):

A partir do Rails 6 já é possível fazer um esquema de pub/sub usando ActionCable

[Aqui tem um exemplo](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/updating-a-rails-app%27s-wall-feed-in-real-time-with-actioncable)

Comment: Amigo, embora esse link possa colaborar com a resolução do problema, seria bom que tu colocasses as informações essenciais aqui - assim, em caso de mudança de endereço ou remoção do conteúdo por parte do site que hospeda a informação, a resposta continuaria válida.

Comment: Veja [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/137387).